# Error: hd1 write error

Tags: linux, ubuntu, hard-drive, ssd

I have a Acer Aspire S3 with Ubuntu 12.04 with `/` partition on 20 GB SSD and `/home` on 320 GB Hard disk. EXT4 in the two.

I was using the Ubuntu normally and then it froze. I could not switch between terminals with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Fx</kbd> and then I made the REISUB.

Well, the system doesn't boot anymore. It shows the message:

```
error: hd1 write error
```

And then boots with only BusyBox.

I've booted with a live USB and tried to mount the two partitions. `/home` on 320 GB hard disk mounts with any problem. But when I try to mount the `/` on 20 GB SSD it shows the error:

```
Error mounting: mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sdb1,
   missing codepage or helper program, or other error
   In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try
   dmesg | tail  or so
```

Result of `dmesg | tail`:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo dmesg | tail
[  855.888087] sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb]  Sense Key : Aborted Command [current] [descriptor]
[  855.888096] Descriptor sense data with sense descriptors (in hex):
[  855.888101]         72 0b 00 00 00 00 00 0c 00 0a 80 00 00 00 00 00 
[  855.888120]         01 84 4a 88 
[  855.888128] sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb]  Add. Sense: No additional sense information
[  855.888137] sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] CDB: Write(10): 2a 00 01 84 4a 88 00 00 08 00
[  855.888155] end_request: I/O error, dev sdb, sector 25447048
[  855.888178] ata2: EH complete
[  855.888182] JBD2: recovery failed
[  855.888190] EXT4-fs (sdb1): error loading journal
```

Then I tried with `fsck` and executing the Journal with no luck:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo fsck.ext4 -v /dev/sdb1
e2fsck 1.42 (29-Nov-2011)
/dev/sdb1: recuperando el fichero de transacciones
Superbloque needs_recovery flag is clear, but fichero de transacciones has data.
Ejecutar el fichero de transacciones de todas formas<s>? si

fsck.ext4: no es posible poner las banderas de superbloque en /dev/sdb1


/dev/sdb1: ***** EL SISTEMA DE FICHEROS FUE MODIFICADO *****

/dev/sdb1: ********** ATENCIÓN: El sistema de ficheros todavía tiene errores ***********
```

Then I tried to don't recover journal:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo fsck.ext4 -v /dev/sdb1
e2fsck 1.42 (29-Nov-2011)
/dev/sdb1: recuperando el fichero de transacciones
Superbloque needs_recovery flag is clear, but fichero de transacciones has data.
Ejecutar el fichero de transacciones de todas formas<s>? no

Borrar el fichero de transacciones<s>? si

Borrando nodo-i huérfano 7280 (uid=0, gid=0, modo=0100600, tamaño=1)
Borrando nodo-i huérfano 35465 (uid=0, gid=0, modo=0100644, tamaño=2100)
Borrando nodo-i huérfano 653083 (uid=0, gid=0, modo=0100644, tamaño=170237)
Borrando nodo-i huérfano 785465 (uid=0, gid=0, modo=0100644, tamaño=25591028)
Borrando nodo-i huérfano 521508 (uid=0, gid=0, modo=0100644, tamaño=83296)
Borrando nodo-i huérfano 521506 (uid=0, gid=0, modo=0100644, tamaño=640424)
Borrando nodo-i huérfano 136007 (uid=0, gid=0, modo=0100644, tamaño=1852792)
Borrando nodo-i huérfano 135991 (uid=0, gid=0, modo=0100644, tamaño=374608)
/dev/sdb1 no fue desmontado limpiamente, se fuerza la revisión.
Paso 1: Verificando nodos-i, bloques y tamaños
Paso 2: Verificando la estructura de directorios
La entrada 'subscriptions.conf' que está en /etc/cups (130337) tiene un nodo-i 131691 borrado/no utilizado.  Borrar<s>? si

Paso 3: Revisando la conectividad de directorios
Paso 4: Revisando las cuentas de referencia
Paso 5: Revisando el resumen de información de grupos
Diferencias del mapa de bits del bloque:  -557607
Arreglar<s>? si

La cuenta de bloques libres es incorrecta para el grupo #17 (1048, contados=1049).
Arreglar<s>? si

La cuenta de bloques libres es incorrecta (1990700, contados=1973157).
Arreglar<s>? si

Diferencias del mapa de bits del nodo-i:  -131691
Arreglar<s>? si

La cuenta de nodos-i libres es incorrecta para el grupo #16 (3, contados=4).
Arreglar<s>? si

La cuenta de nodos-i libres es incorrecta (647115, contados=646991).
Arreglar<s>? si


/dev/sdb1: ***** EL SISTEMA DE FICHEROS FUE MODIFICADO *****

  330289 inodes used (33.80%)
     208 non-contiguous files (0.1%)
     435 non-contiguous directories (0.1%)
         # de nodos-i con bloques ind/dind/tind: 0/0/0
         Extent depth histogram: 267848/114
 1932891 blocks used (49.48%)
       0 bad blocks
       1 large file

  214234 regular files
   33021 directories
      57 character device files
      25 block device files
       0 fifos
      23 links
   82933 symbolic links (62227 fast symbolic links)
      10 sockets
--------
  330303 files
```

If I execute either of the two processes, it always repeats the same. It seems that doesn't write in the SSD.

I tried to remove the partition with no luck too.

Is my hard disk broken?

Edit:

```
sudo smartctl -a /dev/sdb
smartctl 5.41 2011-06-09 r3365 [x86_64-linux-3.2.0-29-generic] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-11 by Bruce Allen, http://smartmontools.sourceforge.net

=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Device Model:     SATA SSD
Serial Number:    11190719090D200B3F09
Firmware Version: S5FAM011
User Capacity:    20.014.718.976 bytes [20,0 GB]
Sector Size:      512 bytes logical/physical
Device is:        Not in smartctl database [for details use: -P showall]
ATA Version is:   8
ATA Standard is:  Exact ATA specification draft version not indicated
Local Time is:    Tue Sep  4 00:06:19 2012 CEST
SMART support is: Available - device has SMART capability.
SMART support is: Enabled

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: PASSED

General SMART Values:
Offline data collection status:  (0x00) Offline data collection activity
                    was never started.
                Auto Offline Data Collection: Disabled.
Self-test execution status:      (   0) The previous self-test routine completed
                without error or no self-test has ever 
                been run.
Total time to complete Offline 
data collection:        (  255) seconds.
Offline data collection
capabilities:            (0x1b) SMART execute Offline immediate.
                Auto Offline data collection on/off support.
                Suspend Offline collection upon new
                command.
                Offline surface scan supported.
                Self-test supported.
                No Conveyance Self-test supported.
                No Selective Self-test supported.
SMART capabilities:            (0x0003) Saves SMART data before entering
                power-saving mode.
                Supports SMART auto save timer.
Error logging capability:        (0x01) Error logging supported.
                General Purpose Logging supported.
Short self-test routine 
recommended polling time:    (   1) minutes.
Extended self-test routine
recommended polling time:    (   2) minutes.

SMART Attributes Data Structure revision number: 16
Vendor Specific SMART Attributes with Thresholds:
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE      UPDATED  WHEN_FAILED             RAW_VALUE
  1 Raw_Read_Error_Rate     0x000b   100   100   050    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  3 Spin_Up_Time            0x0007   100   100   050    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  8 Seek_Time_Performance   0x0005   100   100   050    Pre-fail  Offline      -       0
 10 Spin_Retry_Count        0x0013   100   100   050    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
 12 Power_Cycle_Count       0x0012   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -           204
187 Reported_Uncorrect      0x0003   100   100   010    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
246 Unknown_Attribute       0x0002   100   100   050    Old_age   Always       -               178638
252 Unknown_Attribute       0x0002   100   100   050    Old_age   Always       -       0

SMART Error Log Version: 1
No Errors Logged

SMART Self-test log structure revision number 1
Num  Test_Description    Status                  Remaining  LifeTime(hours)      LBA_of_first_error
# 1  Short offline       Completed without error       00%         0         -

Device does not support Selective Self Tests/Logging
```

Comment: Please post `smartctl -a /dev/sda`

Comment: On sdb do you mean? (It's the "broken" SSD). Edited, thx

Comment: Oh. Yes. The disk looks ok.

Comment: Yes, but I can't format or anything else on the disk. I/O error :-(